# AWS PHP SDK 3.36 GetObject method throwing SignatureDoesNotMatch error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

We are currently unable to download objects from S3, using the AWS PHP SDK v. 3.36. via the GetObject method.

We are seeing the following error:

```
Error executing "GetObject" on "<object path>";
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET <object path>` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calcul (truncated...)  SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
    provided. Check your key and signing method.
    - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <Error>
        <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
        <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
          Check your key and signing method.

<remaining message redacted>
```

S3 Client setup:

```
public function __construct($key, $secret, $region='us-east-1') {
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->secret = $secret;
    $this->handler = new S3Client([
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => $key,
            'secret' => $secret
        ],
        'region' =>$region,
        'version' => '2006-03-01'
    ]);
}
```

Call to `GetObject` method:

```
public function getFile($bucket, $sourcefile, $saveToDestination = null) {
    $getarray = array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key' => $sourcefile,
    );

    if ($saveToDestination) {
        $getarray['SaveAs'] = $saveToDestination;
    }

    return $this->handler->getObject($getarray);

}
```

For the IAM user in question, full access to S3 is provided and the credentials used above have been verified.

IAM policy (AmazonS3FullAccess):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, in v3 of the AWS PHP SDK, if there are additional bucket subpaths in between the provided bucket and key parameters, this failure gets seen.

The following code was added to the method that calls the `getFile` method above:

```
protected function getS3File($s3_bucket, $s3_key){

         /// if the bucket contains additional paths, S3 will choke
         if (strpos($s3_bucket, '/')!==false){
             $paths = explode('/', $s3_bucket);
             $s3_bucket = array_shift($paths);

             /// so prepend them to the key!
             $s3_key=implode('/', $paths) .'/'.$s3_key;
         }

         return $this->makeTempFile($this->s3Handler->getFileContents($s3_bucket, $s3_key));
      }
```

Comment: That is how it should work with any version of any SDK.  The "key" is the complete path -- not just the filename.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize it myself, to be honest. But, you live you learn!

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of digging and found [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=75517). Either:
a) the api keys are incorrect or

b) the Content-Length header is not being provided in the request or

c) a non UTF-8 encoded string value in the request URI.

Hope this helps out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the link provided takes me to your root login page. Mind changing the link? I definitely want to read through it!

Comment: Oops, should be fixed now.

Comment: @JustinFox If that was indeed the error and solution please mark the answer as such, TY.

Comment: I just did so. Thank you!